# Why is filestream returning a length of 0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2015

So I kept running into overflow exceptions here and I discovered that this was evaluating incorrectly. But when I set a break point, the result of `fs.Length - startAt` in code was equal to the exact inverse of `startAt` but in the watch window, the same exactly thing evaluates to the number I was expecting.

[image]

What's going on here? I restarted visual studio; no change.

```
private async Task DoTail()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await UpdateFile();
            await Task.Delay(_interval);
        }
    }, _cts.Token);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Stopped tailing {LogInfo.Alias}");
}

private async Task UpdateFile()
{
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(LogInfo.Location))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"{LogInfo.Location} was not found.");
            Contents = $"File not found: {LogInfo.Location}";
            _cts.Cancel();
            return;
        }

        using (var fs = new FileStream(LogInfo.Location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            if (!fs.CanRead || fs.Length == _lastIndex) return; // no change

            // avoid reading the entire file on startup
            long startAt = _lastIndex;
            if (startAt == 0 && fs.Length > _displayBuffer)
            {
                startAt = fs.Length - _displayBuffer;
                Trace.WriteLine($"File was larger than buffer ({_displayBuffer}). Starting at i={startAt} instead of beginning.");
            }

            long contentLength = fs.Length - startAt;
            if (contentLength < 0)
            {
                // trying to track some weird overflow case
                Trace.WriteLine($"!!!!!! Length: {fs.Length} startAt: {startAt}");
                return;
            }

            var newContent = new byte[contentLength];
            Trace.WriteLine($"This chunk will be {newContent.Length} bytes.");

....
}
```

Comment: I would say it is overflowing for a strange reason, try lesser values for `fs.Lenght` and `startAt` to see if you still get that odd negative number.

Comment: it's overflowing because it's causing me to initialize that byte array with a negative value. I've been having this problem with numbers as low as 33 and 12. It will evaluate 33 - 12 = -12 but only here in code. The watch window evaluates it fine.

Comment: I see. You are hovering over the start of `var contentLength`.

Comment: I actually pinned the value of `contentLength` that is in the if condition.

Comment: Can you repro this in an MCVE? Do other threads have access to `fs`?

Comment: I don't know what MCVE is. This is actually contained inside a method `private async Task MonitorFile()` but it is being awaited in a loop, so it's not being called again before it completes. I can't see any other threads trying to hit it .

Comment: it's hard to see what's really going on in this screenshot, but what you are describing is suspiciously like `fs.Length == 0` at the point that you reach the assignment;  `0 - 276291 == -276291`, likewise `33 - 12 != -12`, but `0 - 12 == -12`.

Comment: Sorry about that - here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - is `fs` a local to that method or somewhere else? Inside the `if` block in the debugger what is the value of `fs.Length`?

Comment: @Claies - so here's what im seeing. If i place a break on the assignment, `fs.Length - startAt` look correct. If I step over it, `contentLength` is correct. I tried this a few times with no problem. If i move the break point into the if block, `contentLength` is negative again

Comment: well, if you move the breakpoint into the if block, then the breakpoint will only be hit if the `contentLength` property is negative; it still sounds like during multiple passes through this function, at some point `fs.Length == 0`.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but this operation only gets run if a change is made to file. It is short-circuited before this piece if not changes were detected. In other words, I save a file and it hits the breakpoint(s) once. So it's not really subject to getting a random iteration.

Comment: It's incredibly rude here to post screenshots of code instead of the code itself.

Comment: I can post more code. The screenshot was to show the outputs of the watch window and value pinning.

Comment: It's an IDE thing though @JoelCoehoorn, OP can you repro this on another PC?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - yeah, lemme hop over and give it a try...

Comment: @JeremyThompson it does not appear to happen on my other computer. I'm gonna restart this one.

Comment: That took longer than it should have. But no change.

Comment: So if I place a breakpoint on the assignment and step through it, no problem. If I place a breakpoint in the if block, then i end up with a negative number. If I place breakpoints on both and step through, no problem.

Comment: did you check in release or debug mode? In the release mode some variables are optimized out so you can't get the correct result

Comment: When I run it in Release, it's still hitting the bad condition and outputting this in trace: ` Length: 0 startAt: 304184` so that is interesting. For whatever reason, length is 0. I also noticed it was output twice. And it looks like the 3rd time succeeded. So... that kinda speaks "threading issue" to me but I can't see how, at the moment. Either that or the file is inaccessible... but it's getting passed the fs.CanRead check and not throwing an IOException...

Comment: you might consider changing your title at this point; you've essentially proven that the issue has something to do with threading and `fs`, it's not a "math" issue.